# What program can I use to test CSS media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries, viewport

I have a site which needs to scale. In this case we scale from 960 up to look a specific way, but then instead of smooth scaling down, we say anything below 960 must be 480 regardless of device size.

So in the header tags I placed:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=480, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

and then in the css I use:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px){}
```

and

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){}
```

My question is, how can I test this to see that it jumps? I have chrome with the Window Resizer Extension. But I am curious if I am doing this right in terms of the settings I have.

Comment: Firefox with the web developer plugin will tell you the screen resolution right in the website title.  Are you looking for something like that?

Comment: it's easy to test. IN chrome right click anywhere on the page then choise 'Imspect element' in drop-down menu. Then you'll see debug frame below the page window. In a left top corner of the frame just click on phone icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desktop browser won't help you. Google for website test on mobile devices e.g. http://browserstack.com. They give a trial version.

Answer (score 1):

There's something in between those curly-braces, right ;)

I've had excellent luck testing *most* media queries in chrome's device-viewer (see image- the thing that looks like a phone on the left).

[image: Chrome's Device-viewer]